# Trying to print numbers in a fashion but couldn't

Tags: java, formatting, numbers

```
7
14 15
28 29 30 31
56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63
```

This is the way in which I want to print but couldn't.  The code I have written is like:

```
public class Numbers
{
    public void printseries(int a, int b)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * b; )
        {
            int k = 0;
            k = a * i;
            i *= 2;
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j *= 2)
            {
                if (j == 1)
                    System.out.print(k);
                else
                {   
                    k++;
                    System.out.print(k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints the following

```
7141528293056575859
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any code to print newline characters...

Comment: if(j==1) System.out.println(k);

Comment: What input could 'b' be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public void printseries(int a, int b)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * b; )
        {
            int k = 0;
            k = a * i;
            i *= 2;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i/2; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1)
                    System.out.print(k);
                else
                {   
                    k++;
                    System.out.print(" "+k);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

**OR**

u can also try this

```
public void printseries(int a, int b)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * b; i*=2)
        {
            int k = 0;
            k = a * i;
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (j == 1)
                    System.out.print(k);
                else
                {   
                    k++;
                    System.out.print(" "+k);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `print()` use `println()` instead. This will cause the console to print out a new line each time the method is called. You may also use the `"\n"` escape character in your print method if you prefer.

Edit
This is probably the code that you were looking for

```
class Numbers 
{
public void printseries(int a, int b)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=2*b;)
    {
        int k=0;
        k=a*i;
        i*=2;
        for(int j=1;j<i;j*=2)
        {
            if(j==1)
            System.out.println(k);
            else
            {   
                k++;
            System.out.print(k + " ");
            }       
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i know that using println will go to next line using that in either of the print methods is not giving a desired output

Comment: Refer to @unlimit's answer in spacing output. You could use System.out.println(k + " ") to fulfill that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    void printSeries(int a, int b)
    {
      int otherNumbs=1;

     for(int i=1;i<2*b;i*=2)
     {
       int k = i*a;
       int temp = k;

       for(int j = 0;j<otherNumbs;++j)
       {
         System.out.print(k++ + " ");
       }

       k = temp ;
       otherNumbs *= 2;
       System.out.println();
     }
    }
```

If this helps. Pleasure.